# Logout methods doesn't work

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, logout, facebook-javascript-sdk

I integrated FB regisration into a WP site. Test site is here: http://teszt.avea.hu/blog/
I can manage Registration user account merge/creation and Login well but I can't loguot FB users from FB so FB.getLoginStatus always remains 'connected'.
I tried the following methods:

- **PHP SDK:** `$facebook->getLogoutUrl();` generates a well formed URL (https, token, etc.). It redirects well, but `FB.getLoginStatus` remains `connected`
- **JS SDK:** `FB.logout(function(){ window.location = 'http://teszt.avea.hu/';});` doesn't log out the user.
- **Cookie solution:** `$facebook->destroySession(); setcookie('fbs_'.$facebook->getAppId(), '', time()-100, '/', '.avea.hu');` also doesn't log out the user. I can create othes cookies, but can't replace FB cookie.

I run out os ideas. Do you have any idea why can't manage logout? Is it a permission problem?

Comment: To clarify - are you trying to deauthorize your app or actually log the user out of Facebook? I'm not sure why I would want any third-party app to log me out of Facebook, tbh.

Comment: After one of the two first methods, if you try to get into facebook the same browser (let's say in a different tab) is the user logged in?

Comment: **Todd:** I only try to actually log the user out of Facebook, not deauthorize.
**Nitzan:** Yes I always opened FB on a new tab (same session) and the user was logged in. You can try it out on the test link. Now I use the PHP SDK solution to generate the logout link

Comment: @Todd it is required that you offer a logout button that logs you out of your app AND facebook (simultaneously).  The why of this setup is lost on me, but is none the less fact.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the problem. I Used both PHP and JS SDK on same website. This cause different token and malfunctions.
thanks